# N2 CMS - all links are green in tree view

Tags: n2, n2cms

I have an existing ASP.NET MVC 3 website, and I installed N2 CMS using NuGet packages. All links are green in tree view, but in `MVC Minimal Example` only `upload` folder is green and all other links are black. Can I change that in code/web.config?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at classes applied to site tree, you will see that Upload folder has class "day", defined in a file framed.css to be green color with code 393. In the same file, on the next line, there is definition of class "week", again green color but with different code 363.

Judging by the names, I would say, these two colors represent site tree items modified during last 24hr and during last 7 days.

This means that all your green tree nodes should become black in a week. Of course, this is just a hypothesis, please test it and let me know what are the results.